# How to fix APT error during the "install the base system" in Ubuntu Server installation?

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, system-installation

When installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server, I get this error message:

```
There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
```

Every time I reach the "install the base system" step at end, and select a kernel to install like `linux-generic`, it shows that an installation step failed. And in the console, the above error message appears.

Comment: you should provide more details...really...

Comment: every time i reach the " install the base system" end and select a kernel to  install like "linux generic" , it is showing an installation step failed.And in the console above error message appears.

Comment: OK.You should **edit** your question and add the details to your **question**. As much as you can.  Also: How do you install? (CD/USB/...), ...

Comment: Are you installing the server edition?  With the desktop edition, you don't select a kernel to install.

Comment: @Ben i am using a bootable USB

Comment: @psui yes i am installing server edition

Comment: Are you able to see any other messages above `There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried type in this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes shim-generic-efi shim-generic-amd64 shime-generic
```

and it might work fine this way, and it might provide a question to your answer.